# Magento: Display more product pictures on single product page

Tags: php, magento

I just bought a template for my online shop and want to change the style of the product page. Right now there is just one picture but I want to add a total of 4. One big picture and 3 thumbnails on which you can click on like in other shops. Here is the link: http://crafts.demo.ubertheme.com/bear-and-forest-stickers-decoration-stickers.html
How can I add such a feature?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

At your admin panel, Catalog > Manage Products. Select your product which you want to add image, then klik image tab. then upload another images. 
Select image you want to be base image, small image, or thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did this already but it still shows just one big picture. I guess it is due to the template and maybe the code has to be modified - but how?